# Error al contar lista con count PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Tengo esta función que me trae los tickets asociados a un id_departamento del usuario que ingresa al sistema

```
function listTicketUnrevisedSupervisor($conexion, $id){

    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *,
     t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, 
     t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion, 
     t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion
     FROM ticket as t
     JOIN usuario AS u ON t.id_usuario = u.id
     WHERE t.status <> '3'
     AND u.id_departamento = ".$id."
     ORDER BY t.id DESC ") 
     or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    return $consulta;
}
```

Estoy intentando hacer el count de la lista pero tengo errores

```
function contarlistTicketUnrevisedSupervisor($conexion, $id){

    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, 
     COUNT(t.id) as id_ticket, u.id as user_id,
     t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion,
     t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion
     FROM ticket as t
     JOIN usuario AS u ON t.id_usuario = u.id
     WHERE t.status <> '3'
     AND u.id_departamento = ".$id."") 
     or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    return $consulta;
}
```

" you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntac to use near * at line 5"

Los dos parámetros &conexion y el $id ya los tengo declarados , incluso el id_departamento cuyo valor se lo asigno al ingresar y me lo trae, que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Cuál de las dos es la que da error de sintaxis? Sácala en una variable,    imprímela y muéstrala en la pregunta. ¿Será que `$id` trae consigo algún dato extraño? Revisa que los nombres de tablas y de columnas están todos bien escritos.

Comment: Es la segunda @A.Cedano

Comment: pasate las estructuras de las tablas, creo que estas concatenando mal el id, $id.. va sin puntos entre comillas simples

Comment: A simple vista no se ve que sea errónea, a no ser que `$id` traiga algún dato extraño, que produzca una consulta errónea, como una `'` o una `"`... o que esté fallando porque `status` sea una palabra reservada, en cuyo caso deberás escribirla rodeada de indentificadores.

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez como hago eso=? lo de pasar las estructuras de las tablas?

Comment: la estructura que usaste para crear o el diagrama entidad relacion

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar tu consulta por esto:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, 
 t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id,
 t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion,
 t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion
 FROM ticket as t
 JOIN usuario AS u ON t.id_usuario = u.id
 WHERE t.status <> '3'
 AND u.id_departamento = ".$id."") 
 or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Y luego despues de correr la consulta puedes correr:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Esto te va a retornar el numero de filas de el ultimo query.

Comment: no entiendo la respuesta tuya @alanfcm , la cosa es que cuando ejecuto la consulta sin la linea del and u.id_departamento me corre en el php my admin pero cuando me traigo eso para el php me da error missing argument 2

Comment: Si lo que quieres es solo contar el numero de filas retornadas, esta consulta funciona, y aun mas facil, podrias cambiar todo el Select por SELECT COUNT(*) y ver si funciona

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion posible seria usar el contador de filas(registros)de php [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)
ejemplo:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* verificar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name")) {

    /* determinar el número de filas del resultado */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* cerrar el resultset */
    $result->close();
}

/* cerrar la conexión */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```